# How do we go from the third equality to the fourth equality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

How do we go from the third equality to the fourth equality?

Ref: Crawford Sobel 1982

Comment: It probably follows from the definition of $a_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Write $c_i:=2i-N-1$. Expand out:
$$
\left(\frac1N+2bc_i\right)^3 = \frac1{N^3}+3\frac1{N^2}(2bc_i)+3\frac1N(4b^2c_i^2)+(8b^3c_i^3)
$$
As $i$ ranges from $1$ to $N$, $c_i$ ranges by steps of $2$ from $1-N$ to $N-1$. Therefore $\sum c_i=0$ and $\sum c_i^3=0$, since everything cancels out in pairs if $N$ is even, and if $N$ is odd you have an extra middle term of $0$. It remains to check that
$$
\sum c_i^2=\frac{(N-1)N(N+1)}3
$$
which you can show by induction.